# JAVA_HOME set but not taking effect

Tags: java

[image]

As depicted in above image java home is set and is being echoed but when i check for version it gives me latest version. 
Already restarted the command prompt after setting env variable.
OS is Windows 7

Update:

Following is the Path.

> ..ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;

Comment: so, now what is your question?

Comment: check your `path` variable

Comment: I remember that java 8 puts a `java.exe` under `Windows\System32`. You cannot pretend it doesn't exist. You may have to use the full path of `jdk1.6.0`, or just uninstall java 8

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same trouble and I solved it with the following steps:

You need the correct environment variables.

To be exactly correct, you only need to set the `Path` variable.

You need to find where you add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the path.

Put it at first place in the `Path` variable:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...
```

where `...` represents all other values of `Path`.

I assume that `JAVA_HOME` is defined as a variable and had the correct value.

After this reopen console and check:

```
java -version
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. It worked.As a side note removing following...\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;  or taking this to end also worked.

Comment: That's great, I just don't like the fact that big companies like Oracle doesnt make that easy

Answer (score 2):

`JAVA_HOME` is environment variable that various application reads in their launcher script

when you invoke `java` it looks up for all paths specified in your env variable named `PATH` and wherever the first match is it gets picked up

so if you like command prompt to refer to jdk 6's Java append the path to `PATH`

Comment: in Path %JAVA_HOME%/bin is there

Comment: some other entry is taking precedence then, what is your `PATH` look like

Answer (score 1):

Windows has this peculiar way of considering JAVA version. By default there is a java folder where jre is placed by windows. It is under C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_351.

And when you will read your Environment variable in windows 10 onward, you will notice there is a path entry "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath". This messes up with Custom java home that we declare. To fix this just **move up** the **"%JAVA_HOME%/bin"** as a **first** entry in path variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to `jJAVA_HOME%/bin` directory in the `path` variable too. `java` command is located in `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`

Comment: in Path %JAVA_HOME%/bin is there

Answer (score 0):

Check your `PATH` environment variable also. Your system is referring to latest Java installation through PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `path` variable you have hardcoded the path to `bin` folder. it should always be `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`.

So that it can pick path from `JAVA_HOME` variable and you don't need to change both the variables every time.